# Trigger action after file upload into server(File exist on the server path)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I hit one question below, could you please help to give some suggestions? Appreciate.

I want to get duration(length) of a videofile upload by user, then update this “duration” into database after file uploaded. --- I already have my own algo which can calculate the duration(length) of a videoFile. What I stuck is I need to run this algo immediately after file saved on the server.

I find "post_save", but it looks this execute before the file upload(before this file exist in this server path, so if I use "post_save", I will hit the error that this file is not exist).

VUE + Django + DjangoRestFramework

Here is my step:

1.Create Voice Model include Field: videoFile(FileField) and the duration of this video(FloatField)
(**Because I need to get this file at the server path, so before this file exist, I set default value for example 0 to Duration column; after file uploaded, then I calculate, and update**)

2.After user upload this file into server, I will run my algorithm in the file path and calculate this duration of this file(input: filepath and this filename; output: duration)

3.After get this duration of this file, I need to update this database immediately

So my question is, how to execute my algo immediately after this file already uploaded into server? And then update database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [TemporaryUploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile) on the django official document which can be used to access the uploaded file before saved to the database.

Here are my steps to solve my question:

1. Access temporary file on the view.py file as below

   ```
   file_obj = request.data['voiceFile'].temporary_file_path()
   ```
2. Using my algo to get duration(length) from the above temporary file(voice file)

   ```
   result = GetLengthAlgo(file_obj)
   ```
3. Save to database

   ```
   serializer.save(duration=float(result.stdout))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So your task is the following:

1. Check django.db.models.fields.file.ImageField and related classes

   - Look at contribute_to_class: it hooks into [`post_init`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-init) signal. On upload this triggers when the model is being created and all field values have processed, so the file is an uploaded file that is either in-memory or in temporary directory.
2. Implement the descriptor
3. Implement the FieldFile subclass
4. Implement the django.core.files.File subclass
5. Hook everything up

You don't need to know the exact time it's uploaded, so don't focus on that event. Django has all the instrumentation in place, you just need to hook it up in the same way ImageField works.

Here's an example of a File subclass to get you started (I use timedelta, cause I have `DurationField` in my model). [UPDATED] Made it deal with in-memory files.

```py
# Example usage:
>>> f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Movies/IMG_0305.m4v"), "r")
>>> video = VideoFile(file=f)
>>> video.duration
datetime.timedelta(seconds=6, microseconds=320000)

# Class:
class VideoFile(File):
    @property
    def duration(self) -> timedelta:
        data = self._get_container_metadata()
        secs = float(data["format"].get("duration", 0))
        return timedelta(seconds=secs)

    @property
    def container_metadata(self) -> t.Dict[str, t.Any]:
        return self._get_container_metadata()

    def _get_container_metadata(self) -> t.Dict[str, t.Any]:
        if not hasattr(self, "_container_metadata"):
            try:
                filename = self._extract_filename()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                proc = self._run_ffprobe_stdin()
            else:
                proc = self._run_ffprobe_on_disk(filename)

            setattr(self, "_container_metadata", json.loads(proc.stdout))

        return getattr(self, "_container_metadata")

    def _extract_filename(self) -> str:
        candidates = [
            self.name,
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.name),
            getattr(self.file, "name", "/nonexistent"),
        ]
        for filename in candidates:
            if filename and os.path.exists(filename):
                return filename

        raise FileNotFoundError("File is in-memory")

    def _run_ffprobe_on_disk(self, filename: str) -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
        cmd = self.ffprobe_cmd
        cmd.append(filename)
        try:
            return subprocess.run(
                cmd, capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8", check=True,
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            raise TypeError("Not a valid video file or unknown container format.")

    @property
    def ffprobe_cmd(self) -> t.List[str]:
        return [
            "ffprobe",
            "-show_format",
            "-print_format",
            "json",
            "-loglevel",
            "quiet",
        ].copy()

    def _run_ffprobe_stdin(self) -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
        closed = self.closed
        self.open()
        file_pos = self.tell()
        self.seek(0)
        cmd = self.ffprobe_cmd
        cmd.append("-")
        try:
            return subprocess.run(
                cmd, stdin=self.file, capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8", check=True,
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            raise TypeError("Not a valid video file or unknown container format.")
        finally:
            self.seek(file_pos)
            if closed:
                self.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Melvyn. So how do you know the user already uploaded the file, I mean the exact time when the file start exist on the server path so that we can run the duration calculation algo to get the duration and update database then.

Comment: Maybe I understand wrong. What is it you want to calculate? The length (in seconds) of the video or the time it took to upload?

Comment: Sorry for that make you misunderstand. I have my own algo which can calculate the duration(the length) of the video. What I stuck is when I trigger this. I don’t know when the file already exist on the server path. I need to update the database immediately after user upload the file from VUE frontend. Because my database include duration field and file field.